# centos 7 .bash_history

Tags: bash, centos

Друзья, поставил centos 7, не могу найти файл .bash_history в /root/. Создал этот файл

```
touch /root/.bash_history
```

но видимо туда ничего не пишется. Помогите прояснить этот вопрос. Куда складывается история bash?

После перезагрузки сервера, созданный мной файл /root/.bash_history наполнился содержимым.

Comment: А Вы из под рута выполняли команды ? Ибо там будет история команд рута

Comment: Да.. после установки обычно выполняю основную настройку сервера из под рута.. а после уже создаю привилегированного пользователя.
Создал пользователя.. поработал под ним.. там все нормально.. стандартно /home/username/.bash_history лежит файл.. и даже сам наполняется... видимо это для root пользователя не работает, чтобы им не пользовались.

Comment: bash пишет выполненные команды в файл истории только когда завершается. перезагружаться не обязательно, достаточно перезайти в систему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

История команд `bash` записывается в файл [`.bash_history`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Facilities) при выходе.

> When an interactive shell exits, the last $HISTSIZE lines are copied from the history list to the file named by $HISTFILE

---

- Чтобы мгновенно записать текущую историю команд в файл `.bash_history` в текущей сессии пользователя, вы можете использовать команду [`history -w`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-history).
- Чтобы история команд записывалась в файл всегда, вы можете отредактировать файл `.bashrc`, добавив туда строки:

  ```
  shopt -s histappend      # дозаписывать в файл, а не переписывать
  PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
  ```

  После разлогиньтесь и залогиньтесь заново, чтобы изменения вступили в силу.